# Problème de compilation

Tags: angular

I have a compilation problem on my projects angular (not a single project, all my projects make me the same error) he compiles the entire project except the node module, and I do not understand why. ideas? thank you in advance .

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Be careful with such title, it should only be written in English. The problems we are talking about on Stackoverflow are tough enough, there is no need to make them harder :)

Comment: Looks like you need to install python on your machine try installing [windows build tooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools) globally

Answer (score 0):

Delete your `node_modules` then run `npm rebuild node-sass` and then `npm install`.

Looks like your environment had changed and `node-sass` is corrupted.

Comment: Unfortunately it still does not work, I did exactly what you told me. But it does not change anything

Comment: Sorry, I had a similar error once and that was the problem.

Comment: In fact I transferred the project from one machine to another, so I sent the project angular on my mailbox without the node module. so i did a npm i to get the node module, and since then ... he puts me this error, while on the other machine it works very well.

Comment: did you rebuilded node-sass?

Comment: Yes, I deleted my node-module folder at first. then I started 'npm rebuild node-sass', it did not give anything, so I did a npm i to get my node-modules. I redid a 'npm rebuild node-sass' this time the terminal reacted and listed full file. I did a npm i behind to update the work done, it can not give.

I said that I care about all the angular projects that I want to launch.